# How to select specific element without using id or classes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to create a on-click function for each button, hence i need a way to select each one individually without using ids

```
<div class="col">
                <div>
                     <b>Name:</b> <span>John</span> <button>change</button> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <b>Surname:</b> <span>Doe</span> <button>change</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <b>Email:</b> <span>doe@gmail.com</span> <button>change</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <b>Birth date:</b> <span>13 May 1947</span> <button>change</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why not use classes or id's?

Comment: Hi Bruce,
Please elaborate on the limitations of your task.
Can you use `<button onclick="someFunction()">` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of selector that you can use if you don't want to use class or ids, even though I highly suggest you to use them whenever possible for the sake of comprehensibility.

Here, you could use the `:nth-of-type(selector)` like this.

```
 // Select the first button of your page.
 document.querySelector('button:nth-of-type(1)');

 // Select the first button of your .col
 document.querySelector('.col button:nth-of-type(1)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of selectors you can use

```
div b ~ button

div button

.col div button
```

You can try the selectors here: [http://try.jsoup.org/~91Zdheyo7rX9PpORdECPjMxb890](http://try.jsoup.org/%7E91Zdheyo7rX9PpORdECPjMxb890)